Android Java PreferenceFragmentCompat addPreference very slow
I add CheckBoxPreference dynamically to PreferenceFragmentCompat fragment.
Code works, but it takes very long time to complete - about 20-60 seconds, depends on the phone.
During this time the app is stalled, and the UI is hang.
If I remove the last line the code runs in less than a second, though nothing showed on the screen.
How can I remove this lag?
Android Java SDK 26
public class FragmentSettingsAppsList extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
@Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fragment_apps_list, rootKey);

        PreferenceCategory prefGroup = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("prefGroup");

        // Set<String> data // DATA CONTAINS ABOUT 100 ELEMENTS, DEFINED ELSEWHERE

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            CheckBoxPreference preference = new CheckBoxPreference(context);
            preference.setIconSpaceReserved(true);
            preference.setIcon(data.icon);
            preference.setTitle(data.title);
            preference.setKey(data.key);

            preference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
                    /* ... */
                }
            }
            prefGroup.addPreference(preference); // <- THIS TAKES VERY LONG TIME
        }
    }


I tried to create the fragment before I replace it, but it does not fix the issue. The lifecycle of onCreatePreferences is called during onCreate so I guess it is the correct place to update the preference list dynamically.
